# Convert int to double Python

Tags: python

I can't seem to find the answer to this on this site, though it seems like it would be common enough. I am trying to output a double for the ratio of number of lines in two files.

```
#Number of lines in each file
inputLines = sum(1 for line in open(current_file))
outputLines = sum(1 for line in open(output_file))
```

Then get the ratio:

```
ratio = inputLines/outputLines
```

But the ratio always seems to be an int and rounds even if I initialize it like:

```
ratio = 1.0
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In python **2**, the result of a division of two integers is always a integer. To force a float division, **you need to use at least one float in the division**:

`ratio = float(inputLines)/outputLines`

Be careful not to do `ratio = float(inputLines/outputLines)`: although that results in a float, it's one obtained *after* doing the integer division, so the result will be "wrong" (as in "not what you expect")

In python **3**, [the integer division behavior was changed](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers), and a division of two integers results in a float. You can also use this functionality in python 2.7, by putting `from __future__ import division` in the begging of your files.

---

The reason `ratio = 1.0` does not work is that **types (in python) are a property of *values*, not variables**  - in other words, variables don't have types.

```
a= 1.0 # "a" is a float
a= 1   # "a" is now a integer
```

Comment: Ah, makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Are you using Python 2.x?

Try using

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> ratio = 2/5
0.4
```

to get a `float` from a division.

Initializing with `ratio = 1.0` doesn't work because with `ratio = inputLines/outputLines` you are re-assigning the variable to int, no matter what it was before.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, Python 2 returns an integer when you divide an integer. You can override this behaviour to work like in Python 3, where `int / int = float` by placing this at the top of your file:

```
from __future__ import division
```

Or better yet, just stop using Python 2 :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast one of the terms to a floating point value. Either explicitly by using `float` (that is `ratio = float(a)/b` or `ratio=a/float(b)`) or implicitly by adding `0.0`: `ratio = (a+0.0)/b`.

If using Python 2 you can `from __future__ import division` to make division not be the integral one but the float one.